# return value javaScript in objective-c

Tags: javascript, objective-c

There is such a function

```
function handlekeypress(elem,event)
{
    return 10;
}
```

That's how i get the context

```
self.javaScriptContext = [self.webView valueForKeyPath:@"documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext"];
```

But i can not get the value of the function(

```
  self.javaScriptContext[@"handlekeypress"] = ^(JSValue *jsValue)
  {
     NSLog(@"%@", [NSValue valueWithRange:jsValue.toRange]);
     NSLog(@"%@", jsValue.toString );
     NSLog(@"%d", jsValue.toInt32 );
     NSLog(@"%f", jsValue.toDouble );
     NSLog(@"%@", jsValue.toNumber );
     NSLog(@"%@", [NSValue valueWithCGPoint: jsValue.toPoint] );
     NSLog(@"%@", [NSValue valueWithCGRect:jsValue.toRect] );
  };
2014-04-06 12:15:55.858  NSRange: {0, 0}
2014-04-06 12:15:55.859 [object HTMLDivElement]
2014-04-06 12:15:55.860  0
2014-04-06 12:15:55.861  nan
2014-04-06 12:15:55.862  nan
2014-04-06 12:15:55.863  NSPoint: {nan, nan}
2014-04-06 12:15:55.866  NSRect: {{nan, nan},
```